# Recommendation for lightweight pedals for use with SPD or without

Tags: commuter, pedals, shoes, spd

Are there any nice looking and lightweight pedals meant to be used with or without SPD shoes? Would be nice to be able to ride even without my special shoes, but not if such pedals look bulky and heavy.

Comment: Have you tried just riding the SPD pedals you have with standard shoes? I find that works well enough for short distances, and my partner rides 10km-ish trips that way quite happily.

Comment: This question was flagged for review as off-topic. It's not a bad question but "shopping" or product recommendation questions are generally a poor fit for a Q&A site like this because the answers frequently become out of date as manufacturers change their product lines. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shimano make several models of pedals with SPD one side, and flat on the other. So they can be used with SPD shoes or normal shoes.
Options include:

#### PD-A530

[image: PD-A530 pedals]

These are designed for road/touring bikes, so are fairly slim, with a small metal platform. (Not to be confused with the PD-A520, which are one-sided SPD pedals, without a flat platform). Personally I use these, they work pretty well, with either SPD shoes or non-SPD shoes.
Weight: 383g (pair)

#### PD-T780

[image: PD-T780 pedal]

Designed for trekking or commuting bikes, they have a larger plastic platform. So they look a bit bulkier, but are not actually much heavier. They have reflectors built in, which is useful if that is a legal requirement where you are.
Weight: 392g (pair)

### PD-M324

[image: PD-M324 pedals]

An older model, with a large metal platform, so a bit heavier. They have the option of adding reflectors or toeclips. Weight: 533g (pair)

Comment: My daughter has used pedals of similar bulk to the last two you show, for 5+ years. With your feet on them the pedals don't show.

Comment: I have a set of single sided SPD's in my box of "good idea at the time, but..." bits I no longer use. They perform poorly as SPD's (The flat side is always up when you want to clip) and poorly as flats (the SPD side is always up) when you have non-SPD's shoes on - '.. they know....' . I not use a doble sided SPD with a big outer giving a flat for dual purpose - not light though so not an answer

Comment: Another vote for the PD-A530. They work fine in my experience, it's no problem flipping them to the other side if they're the wrong way up. And even with clipless shoes, it's good to have the options of using the flat side (and avoiding any accidental clip-ins) on dodgy surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for the PD-A530. In my case I have these on the hybrid and PD-A520's on the Cannondale road bike.

Both pairs are adjusted so that they feel the same so the muscle memory on both bikes is the same. In a panic stop, I don't want to have to remember which bike I am on to get out of it.

Tom

Comment: Rather than repeat an answer up vote and leave a comment.